# Python Scope and Return

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-3.4

everyone.
I'm developing a program that collects data from the internet. In this program, I've made a list of dictionaries and half of its data I read from a XML file. The other half I'm going to scrape from the internet.
This is the function that collects the data and creates the dictionary:

```
def list_names(soup):
    institutions = []

    for name, initials, city, state, adress, neighborhood, zip_code  in zip(soup.find_all('data')[7::7], soup.find_all('data')[8::7], soup.find_all('data')[9::7], soup.find_all('data')[10::7], soup.find_all('data')[11::7], soup.find_all('data')[12::7], soup.find_all('data')[13::7]):
        institutions.append({
                'name': name.get_text(),
                'initials': initials.get_text(),
                'city_state': city.get_text() + ' ' + state.get_text(),
                'adress': 'Brasil ' + adress.get_text() + ' ' + neighborhood.get_text(),
                'cep': zip_code.get_text(), 
                'll_name': {
                'status_request': 0,
                'status_coordinates': 0,
                'latitude': 0,
                'longitude': 0
                },
                'll_name_init': {
                'status_request': 0,
                'status_coordinates': 0,
                'latitude': 0,
                'longitude': 0
                },
                'll_end': {
                'status_request': 0,
                'status_coordinates': 0,
                'latitude': 0,
                'longitude': 0
                },
            })

    return institutions
```

And this function that makes the search and receives the list of dictionaries as a parameter:

```
def search_coordinates(institutions):
  for name in institutions:
    request = requests.get('http://www.google.com/search', params={'q', name['Name']})
    name['ll_name'] = scrape_coordinates(request.content)
```

What I want is that the function `scrape_coordinates` fill the key `ll_name` with values. Both statuses and coordinates. The thing is I don't know what I have to return or if I need to work with scope instead. I've already tested my program and it is finding the coordinates well and etc. I just need to know how if I can return a dictionary to fill this one or what else I have to do.

I'm using Python 3.4 on Linux (Ubuntu 14.04) imported `Requests` and `BeautifulSoup4`.

Comment: Can you add some example input and what you expect as output?

Comment: Inside `scrape_coordinates`, I need to fill the dictionary with the statuses and the coordinates that I'll found. So, where there are zeros, I want to fill them with data that I'll scrape. But I just don't know if I need to pass the list as argument or just use the scope.

Comment: It really depends on what scrape_coordinates returns, if you added a runnable example it would be easier to recommend an approach. Even what couple of  `name's` would help. On a side note there is a google api to do this for you. Also  slicing as your are in find_all seems like a fragile way to get the data

Comment: When you assign to `name['ll_name']` you're modifying the list that was passed to you in `institutions`. So the caller can access those changes in its variable, and you don't need to return anything.

Comment: The Google API returns a different result from searching at google.com. I don't know why, but it's better to scrape the search. More accurate.

Comment: Well, even if  `name['ll_name'] = scrape_coordinates(request.content)` did something you would be overwriting the values each time but as I already mentioned without a runnable example I have no idea what will work

Comment: Yes, `scrape_coordinates` can be a function that returns a dictionary, just like `list_names` is returning a list. You seem to already understand how to write a function and how to construct a dictionary so I'm not sure what the confusion is. Just construct a dictionary and return it. You don't have to make use of the dictionary with zero values that's present. In fact you can just remove that part of the institution in `list_names` unless you need it as a default. `scrape_coordinates` will create a dictionary from scratch and `search_coordinates` will assign it to a fresh key.